# Covering the plane by squares!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, analysis, geometry

$K_n$ is a sequence of squares of area $a_n$. Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty$ then we can arrange the squares $K_n$ to cover $\mathbb{R}^2$.

---

Comments:
-obviously we can suppose that $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.
-WLoG we can moreover suppose that $a_1\gt a_2\gt a_3\gt\ldots$.
-That's enough to prove that we can cover unit square in the plane, because unit square is compact.

Comment: Let $\;K_n:=[n,n+1]\times[0,1]\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N$ . Then $\;A(K_n)=a_n=1\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty\;$ , yet $\;\{K_n\}\;$ do *not* cover the plane. Am I missing something here?

Comment: We can move these squares to cover the plan!

Comment: I suppose in this problem you can arrange the squares as you wan, only the size are "given". If all the square have the same size, it's easy to pave the plane

Comment: More simply, let $K_n = [0,1]\times [0,1]$. The statement is not true. Perhaps, there must be some conditions?

Comment: Oh, you can **arrange** the squares!?

Comment: Yes! Question says $K_n$ can cover the plane!

Comment: Are the square superposable, or should the intersection of two squares be limited to the borders of the squares?

Comment: @Uncountable Those $\;K_n\;$ are hardly **squares** ...rather rectangles.

Comment: If you can superpose the squares, just arrange them in spiral. If we can't supperpose the squares, I think the problem is much harder :/

Comment: There is no counterexample to this problem...

Comment: Superposing is allowed!

Comment: I think this might be true. Maybe it suffices to prove that every  parallelogram of arbitrary dimensions can be covered by a finite number of the squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follows immediately from the fact that [any finite collection of squares with total area $\geq 4$ can cover a square of area 1.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83958/combinatorial-geometry-covering-a-square) (The proof in the link is a little complicated, but the idea is not. Shrink each square so its size is one of 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, .... Then repeatedly find and combine four squares of the same area to make a larger square.)

Answer (score 3):

Solved by CMU Maths Lunch Group. Misha Lavrov was the one who came up with the idea. Basically, the covering strategy is to generalize the covering strategy in $1$-dimensional case.

**Lemma** Given a sequence of decreasing numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots$ such that $\sum a_i^2 = \infty$. Let $n(i)$ be defined inductively: it is the smallest natural number $m$ such that $$a_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+1} + \dots + a_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+m} \ge 1.$$ If $b_i = a_{n(1)+\dots+n(i)}$, then $\sum b_i = \infty$.

**Proof of Lemma** Note that $$a_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+1} + \dots + a_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+n(i)-1} < 1$$ and so $$\begin{eqnarray}& & a^2_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+1} + \dots + a^2_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+n(i)-1}  + a^2_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+n(i)} \\ &\leq& b_{i-1}(a_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+1} + \dots + a_{n(1) + \dots + n(i-1)+n(i)-1}) + b_i^2 < b_{i-1} + b_i^2.\end{eqnarray}$$ Summing above inequality over all $i$, we have $$\infty = \sum a_i^2 \leq \sum b_{i-1}+b_i^2 < (a_1 + 1)\sum b_i.$$

**QED**

We may assume the squares have decreasing length of sides $a_1, a_2, \dots$ and by compactness argument, we only need to cover the unit square. We can pick first $n(1)$ squares to cover a 1 by $b_1$ rectangle and the next $n(2)$ squares to cover a 1 by $b_2$ squares, etc. Lemma says $\sum b_i > 1$, and so we can cover the unit square.